# animating the points of a shape drawn by the html5 drawing api?

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially, I want to alter my shape depending on the amount of content received, so if I retrieve content using ajax and there's a lot of it, I will want to animate the bottom points of my shape to enlarge the shape.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this functionality or if it is at all possible?

Comment: No sorry. I'm still new to html5. I couldnt find anywhere on the internet that refers to the independent manipulating of points.

Comment: Once you've drawn the shape, it's drawn. To animate it, you have to erase and re-draw the shape with the new points. Or you can possibly use SVG instead, in which points, since it's a vector format, can be updated